# Semantic web ColdFusion cfhttp request options

Tags: coldfusion, semantic-web

I am trying to use the following link to get enhancement suggestions in RDF/XML format in ColdFusion.

http://dev.iks-project.eu:8081/engines

My problem is that the list contains the words repeatedly. Can I set some option to get the unique enhancements?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give a sample of what you're pasting in the Stanbol enhancer as well as what is being returned? Are you trying to get the RDF/XML data and then return the data **in the same format** in CF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use and be familiar with [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net) and know how to use Java inline. Then it is simply a case of:

```
<cfset oldModel = createObject("java", "com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory").createDefaultModel().read("http://dev.iks-project.eu:8081/engines")>
<cfset newModel = createObject("java", "com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory").createDefaultModel()>

<cfset sparqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {?s ?p ?o}">
<cfset triples = createObject("java", "com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory").create(sparqlQuery, rdfModel).execSelect()>

<cfloop condition="triples.hasNext()">
    <cfset nextTriple = triples.nextSolution()>
    <cfset newModel.add(newModel.createStatement(nextTriple.getResource("s"), newModel.createProperty(nextTriple.getResource("p").getURI()), nextTriple.get("o")))>
</cfloop>

<cfset outputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream")>
<cfset newRdfXmlContent = newModel.write(outputStream, "RDF/XML-ABBREV").toString()>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the best way to do this in ColdFusion is to loop through the list and create a ColdFusion struct.  Assuming your web service returns a valid delimited list, here's an example how:

```
<cfset enhancements = "item1,item2,item3,item4,item1,item2,item3,item4">
<cfset objEnhancement = structNew()><!---- CREATE STRUCT--->
<cfloop index="item" list="#enhancements#"><!---- LOOP THROUGH RESPONSE TEXT--->
    <cfset objEnhancement[item] = ""><!---- CREATE STRUCT KEYS, THESE WILL AUTO DE-DUPE --->
</cfloop>
<cfset uniqueEnhancements = StructKeyList(objEnhancement)> <!---- DUMP THE STRUCT KEYS TO A NEW LIST---->
```

Comment: httpReq.text will be a boolean value. Do you mean httpReq.fileContent?

Comment: Yeah - this doesn't work with RDF/XML. You can't and shouldn't parse RDF/XML as XML and need an RDF parser

Comment: Thanks David and William.  I edited my response to show the basics of de-duping the list.  It looks like he already knows how to do the http request and retrieve the list from the XML response.